# Are there any luggage storage facilities in Albrook airport, Panama City?

Tags: luggage-storage, panama, panama-city

We are on a round-the-world trip so we have a lot of luggage, but Air Panama flights from Albrook Airport in Panama (PAC) only allow 14 kg of luggage per person.

Is there anywhere at Albrook Airport we can store our excess baggage for 2 weeks while we are in Bocas del Toro?

Comment: I added the country tag, so that it's not confused with Panama City, Florida USA (although I'm aware that the city tag makes it clear).

Comment: When traveling in these parts and using Google, the Panama City vs Panamá City thing is super confusing. See also: Valparaíso ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm posting this in case it helps someone else as I can't see this information anywhere else online. We didn't see any left-luggage facilities in Albrook Airport, which is tiny.

Apparently there is a [luggage storage facility in Albrook mall](http://espanlols.blogspot.com/2015/12/luggage-storage-at-albrook-bus-terminal.html) which charges $3 per day per item, but we didn't actually use this.

Instead we left our bags at the [Albrook Inn](http://www.albrookinn.com/), a hotel about 1km from the airport. Because we're staying there for one night the luggage storage was free, but apparently they charge a flat rate of $10 if you're not staying there.

Postscript: we returned after 2 weeks to find that all of our cloth suitcases were covered in mould, and their contents too, since the hotel left them in a non-ventilated room in the tropical heat. Our hard-sided plastic suitcases were OK. You may have better luck using a specialised storage facility.